# Cat licks her tummy

Tags: cats, behavior

The moment I start to pet my cat, she starts to purr and then takes breaks in between to bend forward and inward to lick the primordial pouch on her tummy. She only does it when she's purring. She's 13 months old. She's been doing it ever since she was 4 months old. Her blood tests, kbc, lft are all fine. She's active and verbal in her expressions. She eats well and poops well.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please tell me, did you notice this behavior causing any visible hair thinning or hair loss in the licked area?

Comment: Is this more of a suckling or a licking?